# localStorage into HTML

Tags: javascript, html

How would I go on to get the information in the same format as it was saved?

Saved as,  example:

```
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', function(event){
const store = {
ci: document.querySelector('.a').innerHTML,
};
localStorage.setItem(store.city, JSON.stringify(store))
```

This is my code, the storage got different keys:

```
function myFunction(){
document.querySelector('.a').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem(i))}
```

Comment: How you save the data?

Comment: Could you add some expected result or output?

Answer (score 0):

Although it was not clear to me what is your expectation or expected behavior. But I will try to give an answer with the limited data.

You can get all the keys in `localStorage` by `Object.keys` method. And then iterate over the keys and `JSON.parse` all the `localStorage[key]`.

```
Object.keys(localStorage).map(key => console.log(localStorage[key]))
```

That should solve your problem of getting the objects from localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem), Storage items can only store data of type DOMString. Converting other data types into a string using the JSON.stringify function is a valid idea!
You only need to reverse this change when reading the data:

```
function setObjectItem(key, item){
    return localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item));
}

function getObjectItem(key){
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
}
```

However, some data types can not be converted into a JSON string. For example, you cannot use this method to store DOM elements.